# How to add new json field to existing json in groovy

Tags: json, groovy

My existing Json looks like:

```
def json_req = "{\"date\":\"Tue, 06 Oct 2015 09:10:52 GMT\",\"nonce\":\"6cm7PmwDOKs\",\"devId\":\"<value>\",\"appId\":\"<value>\"}
```

Perform the operation I can get `sig` field with value. I need to append this additional field with value as below:

```
"sig":"<value>"
```

So that the new json looks like:

```
def json_req = "{\"date\":\"Tue, 06 Oct 2015 09:10:52 GMT\",\"nonce\":\"6cm7PmwDOKs\",\"devId\":\"<value>\",\"appId\":\"<value>\",\"sig\":\"<value>\"}"
```

Within the same script can I append this new parameter with the value in json?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can parse the json with [`JsonSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html), and since the result of that is a [`LazyMap`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/internal/LazyMap.html), you can simply add the new entry to it (lines with `println` added as hints):

```
import groovy.json.*

def json_req = '''{
"date":"Tue, 06 Oct 2015 09:10:52 GMT", 
"nonce":"6cm7PmwDOKs",
"devId":"<value>",
"appId": "<value>"
}'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json_req)
println json.getClass().getName()
json << [sig: "<value>"] // json.put('sig', '<value>')
println JsonOutput.toJson(json)
```

Try it on the [groovy web console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5186434331836416)

Comment: Here sig field value generating dynamically and i am assigning this value to a variable from there how i can incorporate to json

Comment: Simply use the variable instead of the "value".

Comment: You can also just specify the attribute with dor notation and Groovy will add or update it - same as @jalopaba's answer, but add the attribute like this: `json.sig="<value>"`