# Updating Jmeter Json request

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have created a json block file which looks like this, I like to add a new element i.e

```
{
  "Id": 0,
  "cc": "123"
}
```

I need to add a new element

```
"xyz": ${abc}
```

the resulting to look like

```
{
  "Id": 0,
  "cc": "123",
   "xyz": ${abc}
}
```

I have retrieved the file

```
String json1 = vars.get("basePath")+"Jmeter/Results/json1";
json1= new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(json1);
```

How do I add

```
"xyz": ${abc},
```

to json1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate

Refer to this question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988456/how-to-add-new-json-field-to-existing-json-in-groovy

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
String json1 = vars.get("basePath")+"Jmeter/Results/json1";
def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(json1);
parsedJson.put('xyz',vars.get('abc'))
def newJson = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(parsedJson).toPrettyString()
```

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)